# Calculate DateField until days in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django Model has an m.created DateTimeField, how to calculate expire date based with a know number of days 7, 8, 90.

For example, If the m.created datetime stamp is for today + 
valid days is 30, expire datefield should be 30 days from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom save method to your model class. Sample code below will automatically compute expiry date only upon creation. Subsequent modification of the record will not trigger this automatic computation.

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    expired = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.expired = self.created + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want to use the solution above, it better for your code to use signals:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save